How can I have 2 versions in package json based on a condition
How can I have 2 versions in 1 package json based on a condition?
For 1 app - I need to have 1.x version and for another
For 2nd app - I want to use 2.x version
How can I achieve using single package.json
I tried to give different package name but that’s not working .
